# Regression for outcomes truncated from both sides

Tags: r, regression

I have an outcome which is truncated from both left and right sides. I would like to know which regression method may account this kind of analysis. Here is an example:

```
set.seed(123)
z<-rnorm(300)
y<-z[z>=-0.8 & z<=1.2] #truncated
x1<-sample(1:3, length(y), T)
x2<-rbinom(length(y), 1, 0.3)
```

What's the best regression method for modeling `y~x1+x2`?  The R package `truncreg` seems just have arguments for either left or right truncation rather than both sides like this example.

Comment: As Andy W said, Censoring is different from truncation.

Comment: The best _method_ is, by definition, truncated regression. If the real question is what software can do it, then Stata's `truncreg` is one possibility. The documentation http://www.stata.com/manuals13/rtruncreg.pdf is accessible to all.

Comment: I think there is a method called interval regression. Maybe it's helpful.

Comment: They're not the same concept, truncreg and interval reg.

Comment: Sorry. How about non parametric regression? Since this method only based on data.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done using beta regression. In `R` there is the `betareg` package, which has a vignette [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/betareg/vignettes/betareg.pdf).

Another good article on beta regression is [A better lemon squeezer](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16594767).

Comment: Beta regression requires `0<y<1`, but in this and my cases, the `y` does not satisfy.

Comment: Censoring is different than being restricted to a particular range. This is not appropriate advice if the process is censored.

Comment: @Andy Who said the data's censored? The OP said "truncated", & his code exemplifies truncation.

Comment: I need to stop talking (I'm confusing myself), the Heckman selection model is meant for censored data (you can't predict the probability of something you don't observe) not truncated. I see the Stata package Nick Cox refers to has both a left and right truncation available as parameters, so obviously people have extended the original work ([Hausman & Wise, 1977](http://www.aae.wisc.edu/aae637/handouts/hausman_wise_truncated_reg_article.pdf)) for cases such as this.

Comment: @Andy W Strictly `truncreg` in Stata is a command, not a package. I know almost no one will care, but there it is.

Comment: Beta regression does *not* require 0 < y < 1, it is simple to transform the data.